# Python error when using assign operator TOS = precedence[data >> 5] + tabs + delay[D] + tabs + throughput[T] + tabs + reliability[R] + tabs = cost[M]

Tags: python

Trying to get a script to work and it displays an error at the spot listed in the Title.  It is stating that there is an error that says cannot assign to operator. Have looked around multiple sites and even re-watched the video to see if anything was missing.  The video was in Python version two, and the installed version on the computer is version 3.7.2.  So far there has been no luck determining the reason for the error, nor has anything been identified that changed between version 2 and 3 in regard to the assign operator.  Any assistance in identifying the error would be greatly appreciated.  The full script is as follows:

```
import socket
import sys
import struct
import re

def receiveData(s):
    data = ''
    try:
        data = s.recvfrom(65565)
    except timeout:
        data = ''
    except:
        print("An error happened")
        sys.exc_info()
    return data[0]

# get the type of service - 8 bits
def getTOS(data):
    precedence = {0: "Routine", 1: "Priority", 2: "Immediate", 3: "Flash", 4: "Flash override", 5: "Crtiical", 6: "Internetwork control", 7: "Network control"}
    delay = {0: "Normal delay", 1: "Low delay"}
    throughput = {0: "Normal throughput", 1: "High throughput"}
    reliability = {0: "Normal reliability", 1: "High reliability"}
    cost = {0: "Normal monetary cost", 1: "Minimize monetary cost"}

    D = data & 0X10
    D >>= 4
    T = data & 0x8
    T >>= 3
    R = data & 0x4
    R >>= 2
    M = data & 0x2
    M >>= 1

    tabs = "\n\t\t\t"
    TOS = precedence[data >> 5] + tabs + delay[D] + tabs + throughput[T] + tabs + reliability[R] + tabs = cost[M]
    return TOS

def getFlags(data):
    flagR = {0: "0 - Reserved bit"}
    flagDF = {0: "0 - Fragment if necessary', 1: '1 - Do not fragment"}
    flagMF = {0: "0 - Last fragment", 1: "1 - More fragments"}

    R = data & 0X8000
    R >>= 15
    DF = data & 0x4000
    DF >>= 14
    MF = data & 0x2000
    MF >>= 13

    tabs = "\n\t\t\t"
    flags = flagR[R] + tabs + flagDF[DF] + tabs = flagMF[MF]
    return flags

def getProtocol(protocolNr):
    protocolFile = open("Protocol.txt", "r")
    protocolData = protocolFile.read()
    protocol = re.findall(r"\n" + str(protocolNR) + " (?:.)+\n", protocolData)
    if protocol:
             protocol = protocol[0]
             protocol = protocol.replace("\n", "")
             protocol = protocol.replace(str(protocolNr), "")
             protocol = protocol.lstrip()
             return protocol
    else:
             return "No such protocol."


# the public network interface
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print ("host: ", HOST)

# create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)

# bind the socket to the network interface
s.bind((HOST,0))

# Include IP headers
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

# receive all packages
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

data = receiveData(s)
unpackedData = struct.unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s', data[:20])

version_IHL = unpackedData[0]
version = version_IHL >> 4
IHL = version_IHL & 0xF
TOS = unpackedData[1]
totalLength = unpackedData[2]
ID = unpackedData[3]
flags = unpackedData[4]
fragmentOffset = unpackedData[4] & 0X1FFF
TTL = unpackedData[5]
protocolNr = unpackedData[6]
checksum = unpackedData[7]
sourceAddress = socket.inet_ntoa(unpackedData[8])
destinationAddress = socket.inet_ntoa(unpackedData[9])

print ("An IP packet with the size %i was captured.") % (totalLength)
print ("Raw data: ") + data
print ("\nParsed data")
print ("Version:\t\t") + str(version)
print ("Header Length:\t\t") + str(IHL*4) + "bytes"
print ("Type of Service:\t") + getTOS(TOS)             
print ("Length:\t\t\t") + str(totalLength)
print ("ID:\t\t\t") + str(hex(ID)) + " (" + str(ID) + ")"
print ("Flags:\t\t\t") + getFlags(flags)
print ("Fragment offset:\t") + str(fragmentOffset)
print ("TTL:\t\t\t") + str(TTL)
print ("Protocol:\t\t") + getProtocol(protocolNr)
print ("Checksum:\t\t") + str(checksum)
print ("Source:\t\t\t") + sourceAddress
print ("Destination:\t\t") + destinationAddress
print ("Payload:\n") + data[20:]

# disabled promiscuous mode
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: `tabs = cost[M]` at the end of the line should be `tabs + cost[M]`

Comment: You have the same error on the line that begins with `flags = flagR[R]`.

Comment: Do not know how to mark you as amazing, but that was exactly it. Thanks for being a second set of eyes. Now getting a new error message with the % (totalLength) stating an unsupported operand type for %: so going to research that one now. Again thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Your `print` syntax is wrong in many places. All the arguments need to be inside parentheses. This is one if the biggest differences between Python 2 and 3.

Comment: `print ("An IP packet with the size %i was captured." % (totalLength))`

Comment: `print ("Raw data: " + data)`

Comment: Okay making adjustments, and while still getting errors it seems to be all in the print area, so just need to research more on how to properly do this section it seems. Again thanks for the assistance. Been working on this after work for a couple of days now.

Comment: If the script is written for Python 2, you can't expect it to run in Python 3 without fixing things. There are a number of incompatibilities.

Comment: So I'm learning. Only started working with python a month ago and even then it was very minimum, so its a huge crash course into the language.

Comment: Went through and made a lot of adjustments and now it gets flagged at print ("Flags:\t\t\t" + getFlags(flags)) so sure not fully understanding it correctly yet, but progress.

Comment: Did you fix the erroneous `=` in the `flags =` line at the end of `getFlags`?

Comment: Hello Barmar, just got back home from work. Worked on it a lot last night and then during breaks at work and finally figured everything out. It now properly outputs the correct result with no errors.  Again thanks for all of the assistance it really helped understand python a lot more.